Audio-2-face AI to create a talking head from audio and a picture
I want to convert an audio track and a cartoon, or a picture of a puppet, to a video of that face uttering the audio. I found and tried several options, none of them satisfactory:

NVIDIA Omniverse Audio2Face is a proprietary tool from NVIDIA and is the most promising (see demo), especially because it also allows me to control emotion. But it requires advanced hardware, such as RTX GPUs (which I don't have locally), and I couldn't install it on the cloud (question here)

MakeItTalk is an open-source package and also seems promising and can animate photos as well as pictures, but the sample code provided fails to reproduce the results in the repository (with the shipped cartoon and a sample audio, I produced this video, which looks like shattered glass due to Delauney triangulation); in addition, the code has several bugs and suggests it is no longer maintained. (Also, it failed to detect landmarks on the picture of a puppet, but I could work with that and annotate the image manually.)

SadTalker seems similar to MakeItTalk and seems more maintained, but it only works for human faces.

Yepic has good results on human faces but fails on all the puppets I tried. I contacted support and they wrote:



It is possible to animate a picture of a puppet but it would need to resemble a human face. Can you send over the image and I can take a look.
Unfortunately, these will not work with our custom Talking Photo feature as we require a human-like face, especially with the facial features (lips, eyes).


HeyGen has good results on human faces, but it fails to recognize several of the puppets I tried. I emailed support and got no answer.

this news article mentions "Talking Picture" and "Face engine", but I couldn't find them online


Has anyone used AI software to convert a picture of a puppet or cartoon into a talking head?
